# Asp.Net Validation Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have researched the web, used my schools forums, tried to reconfigure all my code to make this work, yet I still end up with this error.  The web form is suppose to validate the input to the fields and throw an error if all fields aren't filled out.  After that it is suppose to submit with the output to another page.  I get the following errors:

Error   1   A local variable named 'errorMessage' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'errorMessage', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Error   2   Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

All help will be greatly appreciated.  This is school homework and I can't seem to get a straight answer from the Professor or students. This is my last resort.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //1. declare Variables
    string errorMessage = "";
    bool OK = true;
    //2.If statements for input validations & coloring text box
    //This is an example

    if
    (Request["txtFirstName"].ToString().Trim() == "")
    {
    txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
    string errorMessage;
    errorMessage + "First Name may not be empty.";
    OK = false;
    }
    else
    {

    txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    }
    if (OK)
    //3. Date validations
    //Add date validations here

    //4. Then the Session codes to transfer data all the way to the end of submit button codes.
    //example

    if (OK)
    {
    Session["txtFirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
    Session["txtLastName"] = txtLastName.Text;
    Session["txtPayRate"] = txtPayRate.Text;
    Session["txtStartDate"] = txtStartDate.Text;
    Session["txtEndDate"] = txtEndDate.Text;
    Response.Redirect("frmPersonnelVerified.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
    lblError.Text = errorMessage;
    }
}
    protected void txtStartDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: you have declared string errorMessage twice and the second time you are doing nothing with it delete the line string errorMessage; and it should work

Comment: Btw. this is NOT how you do validation - RequiredFieldValidator should be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem are these lines:

```
if(Request["txtFirstName"].ToString().Trim() == "")
{
    txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
    string errorMessage;
    errorMessage + "First Name may not be empty.";
    OK = false;
}
```

Get rid of the re-declaration of the `string errorMessage;`, just use the one defined above it.

In other words, use this code instead:

```
if(Request["txtFirstName"].ToString().Trim() == "")
{
    txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
    errorMessage += "First Name may not be empty.";
    OK = false;
}
```

Note: It appears that you want to append `"First Name may not be empty."`, which means you need to use the `+=` syntax to append; if you want to just assign the value then just use the `=` syntax.

Comment: Thank you, while this is elementary to seasoned programmers, I am still learning and this may well be helpful to others.  I could not find this specific problem, nor was sure I was searching the right question

Comment: @webby68 - no problem, I am glad that you are learning. You did the right thing by posting your code and clearly defining your errors. Never stop asking questions. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The errors aren't that unclear. The first is telling you that you're trying to redeclare a variable named `errorMessage`. You *declare* a variable by `{type} {variablename}`, so you see that at the second `string errorMessage` you're redeclaring it.

The second error is that you're using an expression as a statement. It's complaining that it can't do anything with `errorMessage + "First Name may not be empty.";`. The expression doesn't store the result.

So, change:

```
string errorMessage;
errorMessage + "First Name may not be empty.";
```

To:

```
errorMessage += "First Name may not be empty.";
```

Comment: That removed the second error but I am still getting the first one

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same variable-name twice here:

```
string errorMessage = "";
// ...

if(Request["txtFirstName"].ToString().Trim() == "")
{
    txtFirstName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
    string errorMessage; 
    // ...
```

One scope is the part in the `if` statement between the braces, the other scope is the body of the method. Since the if is the method you have two variables with the same name in the same scope.

You just have to rename one.

The next error: "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement..."

```
errorMessage + "First Name may not be empty.";
```

Because you have to assign the resulting string to a variable, you can use `+=`:

```
errorMessage += "First Name may not be empty.";
```

Which is the same as

```
errorMessage = errorMessage + "First Name may not be empty.";
```